# Mod Rewrite not working using .htaccess in shared linux server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using a shared linux hosting and have created subdomain which points to /hrms folder inside the root folder.

Now, I've a mod rewrite condition for this subdomain only which goes like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hrms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/css
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
```

But I'm getting this error when I try to login:

http://hrms.atulmy.com/login

**Not Found
The requested URL /login was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

Also, I tried to check if .htaccess is parsed and when I added some junk, the server gave 500 Internal error, so .htaccess is also parsed and is not a problem.

I already searched for same error in google and stackoverflow, but didn't found the mistake I'm doing.

Please help! Thanks...

Atul Yadav.
[atulmy.com](http://atulmy.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your shared hosting service (SHS) provider provides some subdomain mapper console so the mapping of `http://hrms.atulmy.com/` to `~/hrms` is done through and SHS-specific `RewriteMap` in its vhost config.

1. Verify your assumptions by temporarily renaming `.htaccess`; dropping a phpinfo script into `~/hrms` and doing a `http://hrms.atulmy.com/phpinfo.php`
2. Since `http://hrms.atulmy.com/login` has a REQUEST_URI `/login` your `RewriteBase` should be simply `/` and you should use `~/hrms/.htaccess`
3. You will never match `^/` in an `.htaccess` rewrite rule.
4. You should use a relative substitution string in an `.htaccess` rewrite rule unless you want to rewrite to a different directory hierarchy.
5. You might want to do a proper redirect of `http://atulmy.com/hrms/`
6. You don't want to loop on `index.php` so you need a guard condition, the easiest way is to use a file existence check which removes the need for the existing static checks .

Giving:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =atulmy.com
RewriteRule hrms/(.*) http://hrms.atulmy.com/$1     [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)               index.php?request=$1 [PT,QSA]
```

If you don't like this then replace this last condition by:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/(images|js|css)  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hrms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/(images|js|css)
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?request=$1 [PT,QSA]
```

? Tell me if it works.

Comment: Not working... Its giving Internal Server Error.
Maybe some syntax problem in this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more of your Htaccess file? If I try:

```
http://hrms.atulmy.com/index.php?request=login
```

It sends me to:

```
http://hrms.atulmy.com/login
```